# UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcd8' in position 115: surrogates not allowed

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, os.walk

I have read the other questions and answers regarding UnicodeEncodingErrors, but presumably I'm not able to understand or implement them or the problem has a different focus.

In several years with a more or better less good backup strategy I have several hdds with data. These hdds were old backups of my NAS. Now I want to merge all of them together. Due to the circumstance that many files are the same on many drives I wrote a litte python script. I think that there are pontentially single files which are only on one of these hdds and I don't want to lose them.

I'm working on a Linux-Maschine. All hdds have an ext4 file system. The files on them are from different sources (Linux and Windows). Now I want to attach these hdds one by one to my computer and start the script. The script should walk trough the entire file system of the hdd, hash each file and check whether it is already in a sqlite3 database. In case yes the file would be skipped. In case not the file would be copied to a special folder and a new entry in the database would be created.

On some files the script ends with:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "UniqFinder1.py", line 36, in 
print("Verarbeite: " + cur_file)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcd8' in position 97: surrogates not allowed

As far as I understand this message, the filename contains bytes, which python can not encode to UTF-8.
So I tried to avoid this problem and escape these characters, as seen in other questions.
For example:

cur_file = cur_file.encode('UTF-8', 'replace').decode()

cur_file = cur_file.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')

Although I tried to do the os.walk as bytes. But for printing I have to encode the bytes to string and got the same problem.

With this workaround I don't get an error at printing anymore, but the filename will be changed and therefor wouldn't be found (see error below).

In other attempts the os.path.isfile statement would filter all files which have a modified filename, so first I thought that I found a solution until I recognized that not all files were processed.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "UniqFinder1.py", line 28, in 
with open(cur_file, 'rb') as file_hash:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/anon/Test/Interval Chart Hits #2 - CD1/09 - Major Lazer Feat. Justin Bieber & M? - Cold Water - 4x30-15.mp3'

My problem is, that there are more than 500K files and I really don't know which one of these and how many have filenames who generates these problems.

```
    for pfad in pfade:
        for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(pfad):
            for f in files:
                cur_file = os.path.join(root,f)
                md5 = hashlib.md5()
                if os.path.isfile(cur_file):
                    with open(cur_file, 'rb') as file_hash:
                        while True:
                            data = file_hash.read(BUF_SIZE)
                            if not data:
                                break
                            md5.update(data)
                    md5_wert = md5.hexdigest()
                    cursor.execute('select * from dateien where md5 like (?)',(md5_wert,))
                    results = cursor.fetchall()
                    print("Verarbeite: " + cur_file)
                    if not results:
                        cursor.execute('insert into dateien (name, md5) values (?, ?)', (cur_file, md5_wert))
                        print("Kopiere neue Datei: " + cur_file + " Hashwert: " + md5_wert + "\n")
                        shutil.copy2(cur_file, ziel)
```

I hope this additional information helps to understand my problem.
Perhaps the best way is to write a script which checks for files with problematic filenames and removes the appropriate bytes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UnicodeEncodeError%3A+%27utf-8%27+codec+can%27t+encode+character+surrogates+not+allowed -- if those, as you said, are beyond your understanding, do you really think another question would solve that for you? Which ones exactly do you find confusing? Please, as a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, your whole code is not needed, extract a [mcve] instead.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you don't show full error so we don't know where in code  is problem. if you use Windows then it could use different encoding for filenames - i.e `latin1`, `cp1250`, and it may need to `decode('latin1')`, `decode('cp1250')` (but not `str()`)`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I edited my posting with additional information. 
Last think I tried was to rename the files.
cur_file = cur_file_old.encode('UTF-8', 'ignore').decode('UTF-8') 
os.rename(cur_file_old, cur_file)
It has worked for many files, but not for all. :-( 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "UniqFinder.py", line 26, in <module> os.rename(cur_file_old, cur_file) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: –